# Free SIP tool support header normalization

Tags: sip, sip-server

I'm looking to a free SIP software supporting Header normalization. My requirement is simple: this tool receives INVITE message from leg1, save Contact header and route headers (maybe multi-route headers here) and then sends INVITE to leg2 using this Contact header and one of these route headers.

Could anyone please recommend me a free and easy to use tool?

Thanks,
A.C

Answer (score 0):

The osip2 SIP stack is a LGPL licensed library offering a SIP parser and an API to modify SIP messages. It's very portable.

You can download it [there](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/).

The current documentation, for official osip 5.1.0 is [there](http://www.antisip.com/doc/osip2/).

This is the minimal code required to parse a SIP message:

```
#include <osip2/osip.h>
int i;
osip_t *osip;
i=osip_init(&osip);
if (i!=0)
  return -1;

osip_message_t *sip;
int i;
i=osip_message_init(&sip);
if (i!=0) { fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate\n"); return -1; }
i=osip_message_parse(sip, buffer, length_of_buffer);
if (i!=0) { fprintf(stderr, "cannot parse sip message\n"); }
osip_message_free(sip);
```

More information on parser can be found [here](http://www.antisip.com/doc/osip2/group__howto__parser.html). You will be able to access the SIP Contact header, Route, or any other headers and modify them. Then, use osip_message_to_str to rebuild it as a string and send it.

NOTE: osip2 do not offer any transport layer which is left to you. There is also a "transaction layer management" in osip2, which you may use, at your choice. It's more complex to use.

NOTE2: -I'm the author...-

Comment: Thank AymericM, I will try :)